# Ubuntu software center disappeared on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

So, I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and after less than 5 minutes ( without even configurated the system nor installed nothing) the "Ubuntu Software center" icon disappears and is "replaced" with the snap store one. Ubuntu fully switched to snap store (even changed the logo, I mean: changed the orange beautiful store logo for the snap store default one) or is just a kinda of bug Wich happened to me?
Greetings from Brazil!
PS: sorry about my bad English

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not a bug.  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS's Software Center was switched from being a .deb version of GNOME Software to a snap app.  If you don't want to use the Snap version, you can use this command to remove it:

```
sudo snap remove gnome-software
```

and then use `apt-get` to install the deb version:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-software
```

Comment: So, "F" for the orange icon from the store?

Comment: Sorry, it was gamer slang. So, it's the end for the orange beautiful icon that we used to know from the old store by default? (Orange bag with a capital letter A)

Comment: Well, I really hope canonical go back on 20.04.1 release...

Comment: By the way, thank you to give me a hand on it, Ollie :)